# add a swf to play on top of another swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to have a swf play on top of another swf after a certain amount of time.

can someone provide a code to help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {

        private var _loader : Loader; 
        private var _loadedSWF : MovieClip; 
        private var _timer : Timer; 

        public function Test()
        {
            _loader = new Loader();
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
            _loader.load(new URLRequest("OtherSWF.swf"));

            _timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
        }

        private function onLoadComplete(event : Event) : void
        {
            trace("onLoadComplete: " + getTimer());

            // add to displaylist
            _loadedSWF = event.currentTarget.content;
            _loadedSWF.stop();
            _loadedSWF.visible = false;
            addChild(_loadedSWF);

            // start timer
            _timer.start();
        }

        private function onTimerComplete(event : TimerEvent) : void
        {
            trace("onTimerComplete: " + getTimer());

            _loadedSWF.visible = true;
            _loadedSWF.play();
        }
    }
}
```

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: and then after the timer would the new swf start?

Comment: It up to you to do it in the function usin myOtherSWF.play();

Comment: Make sure to add a stop(); in your SWF to prevent it from playing on load.

Comment: so where exactly would I put the otherswf.play(); in the code?

Comment: what is _referenceToSWF  referring to?

Comment: could you update the code with using swf1 (as the first swf) and swf2 (as the one that plays after the timer) ?  I apologize that I'm not that good with action script, but I'm trying.

Comment: Updated my answer again with a functional class. The Test class is the first SWF (document root class) and loads the OtherSWF.swf on top and plays it after 1 second.

Comment: I am not familiar with classes.  Where exactly would I define the first swf?  both of the swf's that I want to incorporate are external.

Comment: And when I run the fla, it gives me a "packages cannot be nested" error

Comment: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash/